# Does a train conductor have to abandon his train if it is Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work

Someone I know is a train conductor for the NY subway system. (For unfamiliar readers, this type of conductor does not collect tickets, but opens and closes the doors is the main person responsible for passenger safety - moreso than the train driver.)

Let's say the conductor is working his scheduled route, but the train scheduled is delayed, so that he is still on the train when Shabbat arrives. AFAIK, the MTA does not have a means where the conductor can request a substitute to take over mid-route. The assigned conductor must complete his route. If the conductor abandons the train, not only will the train not continue to operate, but passenger safety may be risked. (In NYC, people anger somewhat easily, fights occur on the subway; people get sick on the train, etc. need more ideas?)

Trains are placed out of service if there is a mechanical problem, the train itself is unsafe, or there is civil unrest on the train and it becomes more feasible to transfer passengers to another train. I don't think the MTA allows conductor religious practice as a reason to place a train out of service.

Must the conductor leave the train or does he have to complete the route to maintain passenger safety?

Comment: This reminds me of Uncle Moishy's "Ain't Gonna Work on Saturday" lyrics.

Comment: He should break Shabbat (deorayta) only to prevent loss of life. Just like any other case. What is unique about this case that you ask here? I don't see what's interesting about this question at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA Answer below is sufficient. I wasn't sure if public safety esp. regarding mainly non-Jews was the prioritizing factor, here. Beyond that, there is nothing unique about the subway situation. Shabbat Shalom. (Why did I assume that you live in Israel?)

Comment: What comes to my mind reading this is that if the conductor is Shomer Shabbos, he probably made his employer aware of this at hire, and they hopefully made/adjusted his work schedule accordingly.

Comment: @Gary Correct assumption, which is why I said that the train was delayed. Sadly, it's been a regular occurrence, lately.

Comment: Why is he conducting a train so close to Shabbos to begin with and why can't the MTA find a replacement if the delay is so great (and, if train delays are truly such a problem of pikuch nefashos, shouldn't he, even during the week, walk out so the sick and violent can use more reliable means of transportation less likely to result in loss of life due to life-threatening delays)?

Comment: @Loewian You and I can ponder MTA internal employee policies until the train arrives at its next stop without being stuck in a tunnel for an hour ;-) As stated - the train is delayed. It was not expected to be delayed, obviously, at the time that the conductor began his shift.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3760/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I just read this. I get the gist. But, since this is my question, I have a bias that clouds my thinking. I'm deferring the decision to close based on your and other moderators' consultation.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was reviewing some of my former questions. I see your previous meta comment. I'm not sure I follow your decision of "complex scenario" and why this question would meet that criteria. If you would, briefly explain. I am tempted to place a bounty on this question, but would like your opinion, before doing so. Note that an accepted answer was deleted. I don't recall seeing that on one of my questions.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Agree with DoubleAA's comment. Abandoning his post could seriously risk life or limb. There's also the halachic concept of *hezeka de-rabim*, public safety. When it comes to the public (and this is the public), the thresholds are lowered for both probability and degree of damage that may ensue.

Rabbi Benny Lau spoke of some case involving a gas leak in his town. He said without *melacha* being done they could have simply evacuated the area, but it was allowable to break Shabbos to fix the problem, as it was a matter of public safety.

If he can *safely* do his job just as effectively with a *shinui* (e.g. pushing buttons with his knuckle), that's better; but safety is absolutely priority #1.